# can we share image and text both on gmail

Tags: android

how to share image and text both on gmail?
here is my code but it can,t work.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://pakage name/"+R.drawable.image13);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, data );
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send your image"));
```

Comment: check out my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20015435/1839336 and in code set the type as `shareIntent.setType("*/*");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android send email with text and images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109877/android-send-email-with-text-and-images)

Answer (score 0):

Try using "`*/*"` as MIME, so you can send any generic data type.

Therefore to send image and text,use below code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress); // if you want to add email address also.
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, data);
    shareIntent.setType("*/*");

    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

    uris.add(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.image13));

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send your image"));
```

Comment: sir when we apply this code in my project, it will only share the text but it cant share the image.

Comment: @user3423119 did you try it on device ?

Comment: @user3423119 change mime type to "\*/\*" instead of "image/png",see edited answer.